# Something like BeJeweled game in java language

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to design a game like BeJeweled using java language
This is where I've reached so far :

```
public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final JFrame window = new JFrame();    
    window.setSize(508,669);

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final Grid g=new Grid();
            Game.obj(g);
            window.add(g);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);

    window.repaint(2);

            window.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                int x=e.getX();
                int y=e.getY();




                for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                    for(int j=0;j<16;j++){


                            if(x>i*50+5 && x<i*50+54 && y>j*40+26 && y<j*40+26+39){

                                g.b[i][j]=g.a[i][j];

                                int q = x;
                                int w=y;
                                int r =x;
                                int t =y;


                             q-=50;
                             w-=40;
                                     if( i>0&&g.a[i-1][j]==g.b[i][j]){    
                                         g.a[i][j]=0;
                                      g.a[i-1][j]=0;


                                     }
                                     if( j>0&&g.a[i][j-1]==g.b[i][j]){    
                                         g.a[i][j]=0;
                                      g.a[i][j-1]=0;
                                     }
                                     r+=50;
                                     t+=40;

                             if(i<9&&g.a[i+1][j]==g.b[i][j]){   
                                 g.a[i][j]=0;
                                      g.a[i+1][j]=0;
                             }
                             if(j<15&&g.a[i][j+1]==g.b[i][j]){   
                                 g.a[i][j]=0;
                                      g.a[i][j+1]=0;

                             }


                            }

                    }

                }

            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window);


            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            });


}

    public static void obj(Grid g){

    Random r =new Random();
    for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
        for(int l=0;l<16;l++)
            g.a[k][l]=1+r.nextInt(4);
}

}





class Grid extends JPanel {
private Graphics Graphics;

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    final Graphics g1 = g ; 
    this.setGraphics(g);

    for(int i=0;i<600;i+=50)
        for(int j=0;j<400;j+=40)
            g.drawRect(i, j, i+50, j+40);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<16;j++){
            if(a[i][j]== 0)     g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            if(a[i][j] == 1)    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            if(a[i][j] == 2)    g.setColor(Color.red);
            if(a[i][j] == 3)    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            if(a[i][j] == 4)    g.setColor(Color.cyan);      

            g.fillRect(i*50+1, j*40+1, 49, 39);
        }

    // Mouselis mouseptr = new Mouselis(g);
    // this.addMouseListener(mouseptr);
    // this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseptr);



}

public void setGraphics(Graphics Graphics) {
    this.Graphics = Graphics;
}


            int [][] a= new int[10][16];
             int [][] b= new int[10][16];
           }
```

In this design only the up down left right of rectangles are being checked for same color in the method mouse clicked. How can i make it check all the near rectangles for the one having same color ?

Please help Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four if statements that check the adjacent rectangles for the same color as the one that was clicked. Here is the last one:

```
if(j<15&&g.a[i][j+1]==g.b[i][j]){
    g.a[i][j]=0;
    g.a[i][j+1]=0;
}
```

`j`, the vertical grid coordinate, is compared with 15 to be sure that j+1 is within bounds. Also, a rectangle in the 2d-array `a` is checked to see if it is equal to the rectangle in the 2d-array `b` that got clicked. If it is, you set it to 0 for `Color.WHITE`. Because the indices are `i` and `j+1` this checks the rectangle directly below the clicked one.

To check a rectangle that is diagonally adjacent, change both indices by one. 
The rectangle to the bottom right is `g.a[i+1][j+1]`. To access this rectangle without an error you need to be sure that both i+1 and j+1 are within the bounds of the array to avoid an error.

So, the if statement is

```
if(j<15 && i < 9 && g.a[i+1][j+1]==g.b[i][j]){ ...
```

You can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strong *Object-Oriented programming language* - especially before Java8: I think that you should really work with more Objects that would hold their own responsibilities and behaviours.

Once you'll have a class that represents a `Jewel`, just implement some recursive method to know if it's part of some "Jewel streak". For example:

```
public class Jewel {
    private final JewelType type;    // Could be an Enum for example

    // Many other stuff to add (like a constructor at least!)

    public Collection<Jewel> getStreak() {
        final Set<Jewel> res = new HashSet<>();
        this._getStreak(res);
        return res;
    }

    private void _getStreak(final Set<Jewel> streak) {
        // Just leave the method if we've already visited this Jewel
        if(!streak.add(this)) {
            return;
        }

        // Assuming that this method returns a Collection of the Jewels that are stored West, North, South and East from this
        for(final Jewel neighbour : Grid.getInstance().getJewelsAround(this)) {
            if(neighbour.getJewelType().equals(this.getJewelType())) {
                neighbour._getStreak(streak);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to see if some `Jewel` is part of a streak that is long enough to be "destroyed", just check something like this:

```
Jewel b = Grid.getInstance().getJewelForCoordinates(x, y);
final Collection<Jewel> streak = b.getStreak();
if(streak.size() >= Game.MINIMUM_STREAK_SIZE) {
    Grid.getInstance().destroyJewels(streak);
}
```

I just don't even have access to any Java editor/compiler right now so please excuse me, would my code present any mistyping. Even though I recommend to do many changes, I hope it can help you :)

By the way, if you don't want to override all the methods described by the `MouseListener` interface, use the following:

```
window.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent event) {
        // Code to be executed on mouseClicked().
    }
});
```

`MouseAdapter` is an `abstract class` that implements `MouseListener` and does nothing when receiving any event. You just have to override the methods that handle the events you're interested in ;)

Comment: I have to agree with you. You seem to be mixing the model and the view together very messily, and it _will_ bite you in the butt at some point or another. I would (especially for this project) recommend a [_Model-View-Controller_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern. The model being a grid of Jewels, the View being the JFrame/JPanels, and the controller being the buttons and other user-interactable interface items.